# Not calling javascript function

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, struts

In the below mentioned code when i am clicling on button "Spellcheck".It is not calling javascript funtion.Looking for your positive response.
Thank you

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%> <%@ taglib
    uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%> <%@ taglib
    uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles"%> <%@ taglib
    uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic"%>

<head>Welcome To struts Application.

<title>Struts</title>

<script language="javascript">

    function input(){       alert("Insie input function)
          var abs = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.do
            System.out.println("Path"+abs);
            alert(abs);   
          document.AccomodationForm.action=abs;
          document.AccomodationForm.submit();   }

</script> </head>

 <body>

    <html:form  method="post" action="/index"> <html:text
    property="username"></html:text> <html:password
    property="password"></html:password> <html:button  value="Spellcheck" 
    property="button" onclick="javascript:input()"></html:button>
    <html:link page="/index.do">Test the Action</html:link> </html:form>


    </body>


    </html>
```

have a look at the source code that i saw on browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">







<head>Welcome To struts Application.

<title>Struts</title>

<script language="javascript"> 

    function input(){
        alert('Insie input function');
          var abs = '/MyWork/index.do
            alert(abs);

          document.AccomodationForm.action=abs;
          document.AccomodationForm.submit();
    }

</script>
</head>


<body>

<form name="indexform" method="post" action="/MyWork/index.do;jsessionid=43C03A85FEBE58F375D2165C3E631111">
<input type="text" name="username" value="">
<input type="password" name="password" value="">
<input type="button" name="button" value="antriksh" onclick="input()">
<a href="/MyWork/index.do;jsessionid=43C03A85FEBE58F375D2165C3E631111">Test the Action</a>
</form>


</body>


</html>
```

Problem is it is inserting name attribue in button.I dont know why?Any input from your side friends.

Comment: If that's your real code, then it has some typos in the `input` function: semicolon at the end of the first `alert` call, close the `'` for the scriptlet (indeed, a scriptlet is a bad practice nowadays).

Comment: Sorry for the typo error i have corrected it.but still it is not calling input function.

Comment: @ANk:not it is not working

Comment: I've posted an answer that may solve your JavaScript problems.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` does not take an URL, so the `javascript:` part is extraneous. Kill it.

Comment: I've just made a jsfiddle to test this, and found that it works.

Comment: I ahve removed javascript: part  and corrected some typo mistakes but still it is not calling input function.

Answer (score 0):

Why you javascript function include **java** code `System.out.println("Path"+abs)`, and there some error on your javascript code, see this :

```
 function input(){      
      alert("Insie input function");
      var abs = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.do';
       alert(abs);   
      document.AccomodationForm.action=abs;
      document.AccomodationForm.submit();   
 }
```

Comment: @Jason: there were some typo mistake i have corrected that.Other thing the code is  u posted also wrong please make alert in single column:)

Comment: @Antriksh what's error now, can you see error in console or firebug?

Comment: @jason: i have posted the source code it.I dont know where the name attribute is coming in the button tag. Webpage error details

Message: Unterminated string constant
Line: 18
Char: 35
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/MyWork/index.jsp


Message: Object expected
Line: 34
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/MyWork/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I guess fixing the typos could make your code work:

```
function input() {
    //close the String message for the alert function
    alert("Insie input function)";
    //solve the scriptlet problem
    var abs = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>' + '/index.do'
    //THIS IS JAVA CODE, NOT JAVASCRIPT => System.out.println("Path"+abs);
    alert(abs);
    document.forms[0].action=abs;
    document.forms[0].submit();
```

}

And following the suggestions from other answers, remove the `javascript:` in the `<html:button` tag component:

```html
<html:button  value="Spellcheck"
    property="button" onclick="input()"></html:button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the single quotes will solve the problem

**var abs = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>' + '/index.do';**

If you use Firefox, we will find script error using error console (Ctrl+Shift+J)